# Get javascript accordion to work with 1 ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a nice accordion script from [TYMPANUS](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/10/12/flexible-slide-to-top-accordion/) for my website though the difference is that I am using it multiple times on 1 page like:

```
<div id="st-accordion" class="st-accordion">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Flowers <span class="st-arrow">View <b>Details</b></span></a>
            <div class="st-content">

            <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made  
herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had 
a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of 
Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane.</p>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



<div id="st-accordion" class="st-accordion">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Flowers <span class="st-arrow">View <b>Details</b></span></a>
            <div class="st-content">

            <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made 
herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had 
a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of 
Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane.</p>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please see this [FIDDLE 01](http://jsfiddle.net/5h559dyj/)

As you can see I have 2 separate elements (**I need it to be separate**) using that accordion but because the ID is the same, you can clearly see that the second accordion isn't working.

Javascript for this fiddle:

```
$(function() {
$('#st-accordion').accordion();
});
```

So to get it working, I created separate ID's for each element like in this [FIDDLE 02](http://jsfiddle.net/29k9z24w/)

Javascript for this fiddle:

```
$(function() {
$('#st-accordion-01, #st-accordion-02').accordion(); 
});
```

BUT I don't like having to always create an extra / different ID, so it there a way to get FIDDLE 01 working without having to resort to FIDDLE 02? ... Or is this just not possible?

*The Javascripts posted above are at the very bottom of the javascript section in jsfiddle

Comment: The ID **must** be unique. Why don't you use the class? it is already here....

Comment: The id can not be the same. ID should be unique.

Comment: The rules is ID must be unique. Why dont you use class as selector and use this keyword to determine which one.

Comment: This worked for me in Fiddle2: $(function() {
$('.st-accordion').accordion();
});

Comment: Awesome - thanks guys! Now I feel dumb haha ... though I thought an ID had to be used ... anyway I'm happy that it ended up being a simple solution for a change :)

Comment: I don't know who to award the correct answer to, lol? All of you guys gave good answers but haven't posted them as an ANSWER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can not / must not be elements with the same id name in one page.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.

So to fix your problem, just remove the same ids and just leave the class st-accordion

http://jsfiddle.net/5h559dyj/3/

```
$(function() {
    $('.st-accordion').accordion();
});
```

Comment: Thanks buddy and for the effort - works like a charm!